# VBA dir() returns empty string

Tags: vba, directory

I'm trying to get this vba working. It reads the correct filestructure and it does find the first .xlsx and it import the needed data to the control.xlsm.

I notice that after it gets to fileName = dir() the fileName becomes empty. I read that it does this because it cannot find files that match the criteria, but what am i doing wrong?

Here is the code

```
     Sub test_werk_final()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Dim directory, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet

 directory = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xlsx")
controlFile = Dir(directory & "control.xlsm")
  lijn = 2
  MsgBox "1" & directory & "2" & fileName & "3" & controlFile
  Do Until fileName = ""
    MsgBox "1" & directory & "2" & fileName & "3" & controlFile

       Workbooks.Open fileName:=(directory & fileName)
         MsgBox "1" & directory & "2" & fileName & "3" & controlFile
naam = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value

leeftijd = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value

Workbooks(controlFile).Worksheets("control").Cells(lijn, 1) = naam
Workbooks(controlFile).Worksheets("control").Cells(lijn, 2) = leeftijd
For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
naam = Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets.Range("A1").Value
leeftijd = Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets.Range("A2").Value

Workbooks(controlFile).Worksheets("control").Cells(lijn, 1) = naam
Workbooks(controlFile).Worksheets("control").Cells(lijn, 2) = leeftijd
Next sheet
Workbooks(fileName).Close
  MsgBox "1" & directory & "2" & fileName & "3" & controlFile
lijn = lijn + 1
         MsgBox "1" & directory & "2" & fileName & "3" & controlFile


       fileName = Dir() ' volgende
         MsgBox "1" & directory & "2" & fileName & "3" & controlFile
 Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I'm not an expert coding guru, but i do posses basic programming skills.

P.S: i already looked for the questone on differnt fora en didn't find anything that could help me. Maybe i used the wrong search string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot use twice in row the Dir command with parameters. Dir use an internal status that is reset each time.

Comment: Invert the two first Dir lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simple change the order of the two Dir-statements:

```
controlFile = Dir(directory & "control.xlsm")
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xlsx")
```

When you issue a `Dir`-command with parameter, a new search is started according to the pattern you pass. `Dir`-command without parameter fetches the next file matching that pattern. In your code, you started first a search with wildcards and then a second search with a fixed filename. When you start your loop, the `dir`-command will try to find another file with name `control.xlsm` and of course fails.

Comment: OMG, that explains why it worked with another code. So stupid of me. I will have time tonight to try this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, It worked like a charm. Also thanks for the explaination.